# On the definition of the Reeb foliation

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, foliations

To define  the Reeb foliation on the sphere, one needs to fix two even functions of the from $f:(-1,1)\to\mathbb{R}$.

In the book I. Tamura, Topology of Foliations: An Introduction, the following is assumed in the definition of the Reeb foliation:

$$f^{(k)}(x)\to +\infty,\quad \left(\frac{1}{f'(x)}\right)^{(k)}\to 0 \quad (1)$$
as $x\to\pm 1$, $k=0,1,2,...$.

**Question 1.** Why the conditions (1) are assumed?

**Remark 1.** The condition $f(x)\to +\infty$ is clear. It seems to me that in order to have a smooth foliation it is enough to assume that $\frac{1}{f'(x)}$ is smooth at $x=\pm 1$. E.g., here http://www.map.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/Foliations#Reeb_foliations it is assumed that $f=-\ln|1-x^2|$, but then $\left(\frac{1}{f'(1)}\right)'\neq 0$, i.e. the second condition in (1) is not satisfied for $k=1$.

**Remark 2.** The function $f$ defines the generator of the holonomy group, 
$$\phi(x)=f^{-1}(f(x)+1),\quad \phi(1)=1.$$
Probably, the conditions (1) correspond to the properties 
$$\phi'(1)=1,\quad \phi''(1)=\phi'''(1)=\cdots=0.$$ But I do not see that.

**Question 2.** Is it known, when for different choices of the functions $f$, the resulting foliations are topological or smooth equivalent?